# SchemaAction to add a column to a Cassandra table

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I want to add the column in table (Cassandra ) with deleting the data  when i added the field name in entity class. Previously update is there now it is deprecated. So tell me what we have to use.

```
public enum SchemaAction {

    /**
     * Take no schema actions.
     */
    NONE,

    /**
     * Create each table as necessary. Fail if a table already exists.
     */
    CREATE,

    /**
     * Create each table as necessary, dropping the table first if it exists.
     */
    RECREATE,

    /**
     * Drop <em>all</em> tables in the keyspace, then create each table as necessary.
     */
    RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED;

    // TODO:
    // /**
    // * Validate that each required table and column exists. Fail if any required table or column does not exists.
    // */
    // VALIDATE,
    //
    // /**
    // * Alter or create each table and column as necessary, leaving unused tables and columns untouched.
    // */
    // UPDATE,
    //
    // /**
    // * Alter or create each table and column as necessary, removing unused tables and columns.
    // */
    // UPDATE_DROP_UNUNSED;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Important to remind**

You should avoid letting Spring Data Cassandra create the schema:

- The best practice is to create the tables first knowing your queries and only then build entities.
- Having the entities first tempts you to reuse them for multiple queries with different filters and it is an anti-pattern.
- The schema created is limited as does not have all metadata (TTL, Compaction Strategy) and those would like be different in dev and production.

**Solution:**

- [Here are the accepted options](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/config/SchemaAction.html)

[image]

I would use `CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS` when you have a modification of schema in the table (adding/removing):

- You will have to execute first with the CQL Console

```sql
DROP TABLE <my_table>
```

- It will prevent surprises like delete table for nothing (imagine you point to production...).
- You _ delete the data when i added the field name in entity class._ (and only at this occasion)
- You are not creating tombstones.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent `SchemaAction` to update a table with a new column.

What you will need to do is delete the table manually with the `DROP TABLE` command in cqlsh then restart your application to allow Spring Boot to create the schema on initialisation. Our general advice is to configure `SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS` to avoid surprises.

We understand that the automatic schema creation provided by the Spring Data framework is very convenient however our recommendation is to model your data properly by listing the application queries first THEN designing a table for each of the app queries. You can then map the entities to those tables.

If you reverse the steps by building your entities first then "morphing" the table schema to match the entities then you will likely end up with issues since the tables are not optimised for the app queries. Cheers!